# NASM error: COFF format does not support non-32-bit relocation

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

When I will try to compile my programm, I encounter the error

> COFF format does not support non-32-bit relocation

In this line of code

```
mov dx, info
```

I am trying to display the variable "info".
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use `edx` which is a 32 bit register. Or do not use COFF format. You did not specify what you are doing.

Comment: Of if this is supposed to be 16-bit code, don't try to assemble it into a 32-bit COFF object file.

Comment: @Jester im trying to display "info"

Comment: What OS, what type is `info`, how are you trying to display it? You might have meant `[info]` too depending on circumstances.